# R : Using shortcuts to insert operators writes to a different file

Tags: r, pipe, r-markdown, rstudio, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm sharing a small but annoying issue that sometimes pops up when I'm **using shortcuts to insert operators** while working on a markdown file in R : the operator either does not get written, or even worse **gets written on another file**.

So let's say I am working on the file "report.rmd", and I want to insert the pipe operator using Ctrl+Maj+M, or the assignment operator using "Alt+-", and I have the file "test.R" opened. Well, I therefore type the aforementioned shortcuts and...nothing happens on my markdown file. But some nice operators that had nothing to do there get written on my test.R file.

The only way I found to solve this problem is to close and reopen RStudio (restarting unfortunately doesn't solve the issue).

While this is quite a minor problem, it's incredibly annoying. Did it ever happen to anyone of you, and if so do you know where it comes from and how to solve it?

**Edit**:
Although I am still running into this issue (without being able to reproduce it consistently) I came into a somewhat lighter solution. Instead of restarting R, simply **closing all tabs** (closing just the problematic one doesn't work) solves the problem. I hope this helps narrowing down the possible origins of the problem.

Comment: That sounds like a frustrating problem. It isn't perfectly clear to me what the sequence of events and inventory of open tabs would be, can you produce a literal sequence of actions, starting with *"open RStudio IDE"* (with no tabs open yet)? It might turn into a good reprex for a bug-report, depending on what we see. Thanks!

Comment: You may also ask on [RStudio Community](https://community.rstudio.com/), they have a category "RStudio IDE" (but modify your post as @r2evans suggested)

Comment: @r2evans I would very much like to do so, but unfortunately as I mentionned, the problem "randomly" happens (I wasn't able to idenify the root of it nor the sequence of actions that triggers it). Therefore I am at the moment not able to reproduce it. For example right now I am working on a markdown file and the operator insertion shortcuts work perfectly

Answer (score 2):

### Short Answer

re-define the key combo to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>\</kbd>  , assuming this does not create a conflict

### Background

I've had a similar problem for a while, too. In my case, the shortcut never works. I can not find the source. I even found a conflict with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> assigned to 2 *Editor* functions.

Image:[Screen Capture 2 conflicting hotkey assignments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzX8m.png)

However, a simple key reassignment of the one that is not the pipe operator (*"Expand to Matching"*)

Image:[screen capture showing the hotkey conflict solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4nDH.png)**didn't** solve the issue in my case.

### Solution

**Here's what did the job for me**

I managed to assign a different combo (that hasn't been assigned yet) and that is comfortable enough in the sense of its location on the keyboard

1. go to  <kbd>Tools → Modify Keyboard Shortcuts...</kbd>
2. In the filter box, write "Pipe"
3. Direct the cursor to the text box showing the current shortcut, and press the new combo (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>\</kbd>  ), then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Remember to hit **Apply**
5. Make sure the new Combo isn't a duplicate of another command, by going back to step 1 and sorting the list by Shortcut, then scrolling down to find your new one. if there is an ovelap, consider changing one of them.

Comment: Thank you very much, I hope this works. I was still having this problem while not being able to reproduce it or locate the error. I hope this solves it. I will try it for a few days and comment back to document on wether I still have this problem or not.

Comment: I'm unfortunately still running into the error. I'll try different bindings but this error is incredibly annoying...

Comment: curious. so far I have not experienced more issues with the new key binding. I am planning to open a new post about it in R studio Community, whenever i get to it. I'll post a link when i do

Comment: Did you continue running into the same error w the new binding ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, changing the bindings and making sure there was no conflicts didn't do the trick. I am still unable to consistently reproduce the error, it just seems to pop up at random. Maybe a clue to the answer come from the fact that the error disappears when I'm closing all files then reopening them.